# Why do [closed] questions still show up?

Tags: support

I just noticed that a question that was closed yesterday was responded to today, thereby bumping it to the top. Is that normal? I don't recall seeing this on SO, but I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It certainly does happen on Stack Overflow, it's just that the activity level is so high there that they tend to get bumped down pretty quickly.

Closed questions don't disappear.  The concept of a closed question is that it is *probably* going to be deleted at some point, but until then (at least 2 days), the author - or anyone else - can try to edit it into shape, or plead their case on meta.

Normally, you need to have 10k reputation to vote to delete questions.  During the beta period, it's 2k.  And speaking of which, I put in several votes to delete the other day but didn't get any help (they've since aged away).  As the "sous-moderators" here, we all need to do our part with deletions.

FYI, the general thought on Stack Overflow (or at least MSO) is that we only delete Off-Topic/S&A/NARQ questions; duplicates are candidates for merges instead, which is something that needs to be done by diamond mods.  We don't have any yet, but for now, I guess just leave them alone, and vote to delete any other closed questions after 2 days (unless you see a reason to keep them around).

Comment: Ah. I've never made it to 10k on SO so I don't know what delete etiquette was. I assumed it was only to be used in the direst of circumstances.

Comment: Well I went through and delete voted the 5 I could for today. Some just need one more vote. This seems like it's something that won't see much follow through for now though. I don't normally search for closed questions.

Comment: @hobodave: Indeed, janitorial work is tedious at the best of times, and it'll only get worse once people start whining at you about it.  But the site needs it.  Otherwise those closed questions just linger around in the search results and may even get bumped, as you witnessed today.